# How to detect on long press(May be for 4 min) to move object continuously on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview

Greeting,

I have taken a `canvas`by using `Surface View`.and i am moving the surface to showing movement in 
object. But my problem is that if i press canvas then some object will be moved until, user do not release the pressure from canvas. I have tried the action_down in touch event.But it work
only one time. So i have to touch again and again to move object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so two things about on touch events. one always return true if you want to use them and keep them on your view. two use the action_move

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        saveEvent = event;
    }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        //diff savedEvent and event
        //on 2.0 above its getX(0)
        diffX = event.getX() - savedEvent.getX();
        diffY = event.getY() - savedEvent.getY();
        moveObject(diffX,diffY);
        savedEvent = event;
    }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        savedEvent = null;
    }
    return true;
 }
```